# Error in file upload

Tags: php, mysql

This is my script:

```
$today = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("y"));
$b= date("m/d/y", $today);     

if ($_FILES["file$i"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file$i"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
      else
        {
        // echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        // echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        // echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        // echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
            $upload=$_FILES["file$i"]["name"];
            $fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '', $upload);
            $filup=$b.$fileName;
            echo $filup;
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $filup))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file$i"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file$i"]["tmp_name"],
          "upload/" . $filup);
          $path="upload/" . $filup;
          $temp="Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
          $sql="insert into album(uid,path,cid,title) values('$uid','$path','$cid','$text[$i]') ";
          mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
          }
        }
```

It is showing me this error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/06/20/113.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\demo\editedfileupload\pr1\upload_file.php on line 31

Line 31 is:

```
echo $_FILES["file$i"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
```

Comment: Given that the warning says `move_uploaded_file(upload/06/20/113.jpg)`, I'd guess line 31 is actually `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file$i"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $filup);`. Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: yes this file exists, if i use $upload instead of using $filup, it works fine. When i used date time stamp, only then the following error occurs.

Comment: Could it be that Windows does not allow file and folder names with forward slashes in them like you have used in the date?

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to check if your problem is fixed or are you still seeing the error? Can you please choose the best answer, if any, that answered your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that `$filup` isn't what you may think it is. When you are doing `$filup=$b.$fileName;`, you might be inadvertently changing the complete path for the file. For example, assume:

```
$b = "06/20/11"
$fileName = "testfile"
```

Then after doing `$filup=$b.$fileName;`, $filup will become:

```
$filup = "06/20/11testfile"
```

So, when you use $filup in file_exists() or move_uploaded_file(), what might be happening is that the slashes in $fileup are taken for directory separators instead of the filename.

So the check (file_exists('upload/06/20/11testfile') always fail and when it goes to move_uploaded_file, it says "no such file or directory".

Please consider removing the forward slashes from $b or using "-" instead. I think even escaping the "/" should work but I'd suggest to keep it simple if there are no specific reasons to keep slashes.

On another note, I'd suggest using absolute paths for file-system operations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user799100: I think my response also explains your comment above - "yes this file exists, if i use $upload instead of using $filup, it works fine. When i used date time stamp, only then the following error occurs"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think line 31 is the one you selected, but the error for sure is caused by this code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file$i"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $filup);
```

Now, typically, I would say this is a CHMOD issue, but there are some weird things happening, which I am not all too familiar with (since you are working from a Windows system). Check the CHMOD and if that fixes it, good for you, but otherwise, please explain how it's possible that variable `$b` contains forward slashes? Windows works with backward slashes (and this probably holds true within PHP as well). See if changing the slashes will make a difference.

EDIT: based on your comment to your own post, I'm fairly sure that this issue is caused by the forward slashes. You can still use the `$fileName` variable, but make sure the `$b` variable doesn't contain forward slashes. Also, in the lines `if (file_exists("upload/" . $filup))` and `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file$i"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $filup);`, change the forward slashes to backward slashes.